# Hex characters in regexp matching in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I've spot very odd behavior of mysql.
The select below returns 0:

```
SELECT CONVERT('a' USING BINARY) REGEXP '[\x61]'
```

However semantically identical select below returns 1:

```
SELECT CONVERT('a' USING BINARY) REGEXP '[\x61-\x61]'
```

Do you know what is happening here?
I've tested that in mysql 5.0.0.3031 and 4.1.22

I need the hex characters to create a regexp that match when a binary string is encoded in utf8. A perl version of such regexp can be found on [w3c site](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8.en.php). It looks as follow:

```
$field =~
      m/\A(
         [\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]            # ASCII
       | [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
       |  \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding overlongs
       | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
       |  \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding surrogates
       |  \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # planes 1-3
       | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
       |  \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # plane 16
      )*\z/x;
```

Comment: I removed the `utf-8` tag because this question is purely about MySQL's regex flavor.  Your other question is the one that deals with the UTF-8 aspects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199825/how-can-i-check-if-a-binary-string-is-utf-8-in-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This matches too:

```
SELECT CONVERT('a' USING BINARY) REGEXP '[1-\x]'
```

The reason is that `\x` is interpeted as `x` and `a` comes between `1` and `x`. The rest of your regex is just ordinary characters that aren't relevant here because they're already inside the [1-x] range.

```
SELECT CONVERT('0' USING BINARY) REGEXP '[\x61-\x61]' -- Fails, because 0 < 1.
SELECT CONVERT('1' USING BINARY) REGEXP '[\x61-\x61]' -- Succeeds: inside [1-x].
SELECT CONVERT('2' USING BINARY) REGEXP '[\x61-\x61]' -- Succeeds: inside [1-x].
...
SELECT CONVERT('w' USING BINARY) REGEXP '[\x61-\x61]' -- Succeeds: inside [1-x].
SELECT CONVERT('x' USING BINARY) REGEXP '[\x61-\x61]' -- Succeeds: inside [1-x].
SELECT CONVERT('y' USING BINARY) REGEXP '[\x61-\x61]' -- Fails, because y > x.
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you want hex characters, you can use the hex function:

```
SELECT HEX('a')
61
```

Comment: That's shame :(. I've tried to port this reqexp to mysql http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8.en.php

Answer (score 4):

to write a regexp like `[\x61-\x65]` in mysql, you can use hex values inside a concat:

```
SELECT CONVERT('a' USING BINARY) REGEXP CONCAT('[', 0x61, '-', 0x65, ']')
```

Answer (score 3):

Lol... based on the above you can just use the print characters. That worked for me. I wanted to make it match characters not on a USA keyboard and the following expression works on MySQL 5.1:

```
[^ -~]
```

That will do the same thing as

```
[^\x20-\x7E]
```

Comment: +1 good point! on the other hand it might get tricky with number above 0x7E

Comment: It worked with prettymuch everything i needed. `...AND l.Description NOT RLIKE "[\n“”’¿½–é° ±…•—â™€¾‘¢¼®ç²º àóªáíñ·­]+"`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to check for UTF-8 encoded characters in a latin-1 column, expanding on the answer by Puggan Se gave me:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) from myTable where CONVERT(myCol  USING BINARY) REGEXP CONCAT('[',0xF0,'-',0xFF,']','[', 0x80, '-', 0xBF, ']') limit 3;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.54 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) from myTable where CONVERT(myCol  USING BINARY) REGEXP CONCAT('[',0xE0,'-',0xEF,']','[', 0x80, '-', 0xBF, ']') limit 3;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.53 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) from myTable where CONVERT(myCol  USING BINARY) REGEXP CONCAT('[',0xC2,'-',0xDF,']','[', 0x80, '-', 0xBF, ']') limit 3;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.50 sec)

mysql>
```

The limit is there for when I don't count lines, inverting the last range in the regexp showed me that there actually was extended characters in there (giving me confidence that the regexp works since it have not found any broken data for me yet).
Ref: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm